# jQuery Toggle Between Functions Fn1 Fn2 Fn3 On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way of toggling between different functions, on click events ? Something maybe that use "on" "off" methods or simpler alternative ?

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.clickToggle = function(func1, func2, func3) {
            var funcs = [func1, func2, func3];
            this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
            this.click(function() {
                var data = $(this).data();
                var tc = data.toggleclicked;
                $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
                data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % 3;
            });
            return this;
        };
    }(jQuery));

    $('#b1').clickToggle(
        function() {alert('First handler');}, 
        function() {alert('Second handler');},
        function() {alert('Third handler');}
        );
```

Comment: I think this is a good method. I think using `.off()` and `.on()` to change the handler won't work, because when the next handler is added with `.on()`, and the old handler returns, it will then run the next handler immediately.

Comment: That will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your general approach seems sound. But you shouldn't hard-code the number of handlers. Take the functions as a rest-arg, and use `funcs.length` in the modulo expression.

You can also use the argument to `.data()` to look up the named data element, rather than getting the whole data object.

```
$.fn.clickToggle = function(...funcs) {
    this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
    this.click(function() {
        var tc = $(this).data("toggleclicked");
        $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
        data.toggleclicked = (tc + 1) % funcs.length;
    });
    return this;
};
```

You might also want to special-case a single function and just bind it the normal way, and completely ignore the call if there are no functions.

```
$.fn.clickToggle = function(...funcs) {
    switch (funcs.length) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        this.click(funcs[0]);
        break;
    default:
        this.data('toggleclicked', 0);
        this.click(function() {
            var tc = $(this).data("toggleclicked");
            $.proxy(funcs[tc], this)();
            $(this).data("toggleclicked", (tc + 1) % funcs.length);
        });
    }
    return this;
};
```